# add custom image to category

Tags: product

i want to add custom image to category add and save that image , how can i do it  i am able to add custom text file with below code:

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$attribute1  = array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'label'=> 'Image Path',
    'input' => 'text',
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'default' => "",
    'group' => "General Information"
);

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'image_path', $attribute1);
$installer->endSetup();
?>
```

but i want to add input type image and save that image pls guide

Comment: You mean aside from the main category image and thumbnail image included in the core?

Comment: yeah i want to add extra one beside it , one thing also where does magento uses category thumbnail images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you simply add new image attribute?

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'my_image', array(
    'type'          => 'varchar',
    'label'         => 'My Image',
    'input'         => 'image',
    'backend'       => 'catalog/category_attribute_backend_image',
    'required'      => false,
    'sort_order'    => 99,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'group'         => 'General Information'
));
```

Comment: will it automatically save images

Comment: Yes it will. You can look at `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Attribute_Backend_Image` for further reference.

Comment: hi what to do to resize image before saving

Comment: You can create your own backend model and use Varien_Image to resize.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you not define  **input field and  and backed model** for this attribute.

Your `input` Should be  `image` from

and `Backend model` Should be  `catalog/category_attribute_backend_image`.

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();


    $installer->addAttribute("catalog_category", "image_path",  array(
        "type"     => "varchar",
        "backend"  => "catalog/category_attribute_backend_image",
        "frontend" => "",
        "label"    => "Image Path",
        "input"    => "image",
        "class"    => "",
        "source"   => "",
        "global"   => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,,
        "visible"  => true,
        "required" => false,
        "user_defined"  => false,
        "default" => "",
        "searchable" => false,
        "filterable" => false,
        "comparable" => false,
        'group'         => 'General Information'
        "visible_on_front"  => false,
        "unique"     => false,
        "note"       => ""

        ));
    $installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: Its not working...